# Mean Absolute Error vs Mean Squared Error

Tags: linear-regression

why MAE is not used widely unlike MSE?
In what scenarios you would prefer to use one over the other. Explain mathematically too.
I was asked in an interview. I referred [MSE vs MAE in linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/582238/mae-vs-mse-for-linear-regression)

The reason I shared to my interviewer were which was not enough :
MAE is robust to outliers.

Further I think that MSE could be differentiated , we minimize it using Gradient descent
Also , MSE is assumed to be normally distributed and in case of outlier the mean would be shifted. It will be skewed distribution

Further my question is why just squared only , why do not cube the errors. Please pardon me if I am missing something crude mathematically. I am not from core maths background